# How deploy with maven-glassfish-plugin on my Linux server?

Tags: linux, maven, glassfish, maven-plugin, maven-glassfish-plugin

I try to deploy my web application on **Linux** Server.

When I deploy on local Server GlassFish : It's ok.
But, when I try to deploy on Linux Server Glassfish : maven try to call "**asadmin.bat**" in my  local computer (OS : Windows). So Build is failed. I want Maven call "**asadmin shell script**" on the Linux Server.

How can I declare to `maven-glassfish-plugin` the server Linux ?

Answer (score 1):

You have to use a local asadmin.bat to delpoy on the remote Linux-Server.

Configure the `maven-glassfish-plugin` so that the glassfish-dir points on a local glassfish(windows) e.g.:

```
<plugin>
                <groupId>org.glassfish.maven.plugin</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-glassfish-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <glassfishDirectory>C:\glassfish3\glassfish</glassfishDirectory>
                    <user>remote_admin</user>
                    <adminPassword>remote_adminPassword</adminPassword>
                    <domain>
                        <name>remote_domain</name>
                        <host>remote_host</host>
                        <adminPort>remote_adminPort(4848)</adminPort>
                    </domain>
                    <components>
                        <component>
                            <name>${project.artifactId}</name>
                        <artifact>${project.build.directory}/${project.build.finalName}.war</artifact>
                        </component>
                    </components>
                </configuration>
....
<plugin>
```

Comment: i tired your approch. still i was getting org.apache.maven.plugin.prefix.NoPluginFoundForPrefixException . no glassfish plugin